# How to insert words in a numpy multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to put in a matrix some words that are taken from a list, based on their indices.
My code is the following:

```
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    for j in range(no_of_lines):
        cuv_matrix[i][j] = cuv_list[mat_index[i][j]]
```

cuv_list is the list of words, and mat_index contains the indices that correspond to the ones in the cuv_list

The cuv_matrix actual output is this:

```
[['\x88' 'M' '\x93' ..., '6' '4' '1']
 ['2' '8' '3' ..., '0' '1' '6']
 ['0' '3' '2' ..., '.' '0' '0']
 ..., 
 ['\xff' '\xff' '\xff' ..., '' '0' '.']
 ['0' '' '0' ..., '' '0' '.']
 ['0' '' '0' ..., '0' '.' '0']]
```

The way I declared cuv_matrix:

```
cuv_matrix = numpy.chararray((no_of_lines, no_of_lines))
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get each element of the matrix to be a word, like this?

Expected output:

```
[[movie film ..., actor]
      ... ...
character seen ..., director]]
```

Later on, I need to access the words from the matrix using their coordinates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should update your question to include actual and expected output

Comment: I have specified now the actual and expected output.

Comment: _why_ do you want to put strings into a numpy array?

Comment: I don't know, I just want to have the words in a matrix so that I can access them simply by going twice with for...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, cuv_list is just a list, right?

so, you need an external counter.

```
k = 0
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    for j in range(no_of_lines):
        cuv_matrix[i][j] = cuv_list[k]
        k += 1
```

Looking at your question again, it seems like you might also want a dictionary to hold info:

```
cuv_mat = {}
k = 0
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    for j in range(no_of_lines):
        cuv_matrix[i][j] = cuv_list[k]
        cuv_mat[cuv_list[k]] = (i,j)
        k += 1
```

Or, in the case that you want to keep the coordinate info together with the original list and might have duplicates:

```
cuv_mat_locations = []
k = 0
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    for j in range(no_of_lines):
       cuv_matrix[i][j] = cuv_list[k]
       cuv_mat_locations.append([cuv_list[k], [i,j]])
       k += 1
```

Comment: cuv_list is a list, but the order in which the words need to be put in the cuv_matrix is important. The mat_index matrix contains indices, that are used as "pointers" to the cuv_list. That way, mat_index gives the order in which the words are taken from the cuv_list and put into the cuv_matrix.

Comment: I was editing at the same time as your comment - my current suggestion adds a dictionary entry for each item in the list that contains a tuple of the coordinates. However, that can be problematic if there are duplicate keys.